# Not getting attribute from a xml file into asp

Tags: asp-classic, xml-parsing

I have the following xml result from this link - https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=BorisKarlov

```
<eveapi version="2">
<currentTime>2013-01-16 18:57:38</currentTime>
<result>
<rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID">
<row name="BorisKarlov" characterID="315363291"/>
</rowset>
</result>
<cachedUntil>2013-02-16 18:57:38</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

and I am trying to extract the characterID into asp.  I am using the following code,

```
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
oXML.LoadXML("https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=BorisKarlov")

Set oRoot = oXML.selectSingleNode("//result")

For Each oNode In oRoot.childNodes
  response.Write oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("characterID").Text
Next 

Set oXML = Nothing
```

All i keep getting is the following error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'oRoot'

.............

I can only assume that Set oRoot = oXML.selectSingleNode("//result") is not actually generating any data and therefore throwing up the error in the next line.

Can anyone please shed some light on my problem?

Comment: Try adding `oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"`

Comment: thank you for your reply, i've added that line but still getting the Object required: 'oRoot' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems there.

1. [loadXML()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for loading a block of XML as a string, not fetching from a remote server; for that, you need to use [load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. when loading from a server, you need to tell it to use the [ServerXMLHTTP component](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281142), and set async to false so that it waits until loaded before executing the rest of your script.
3. when I tried loading that XML, I got an encoding error; you will need to resolve that [one way or another](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304625)
4. when I loaded the XML directly from a string, it wouldn't parse because there is a script element containing non-XML content; that needs to be contained within a [CDATA section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256076%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
5. your XPath query is to `//result`, but you actually need it to be `//result/rowset`

This code should work once you resolve issues 3 and 4 above:

```
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
oXML.async = False
oXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true

oXML.Load("https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=BorisKarlov")

If oXML.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    Response.Write "<p>XML parse error: " & Server.HTMLEncode(oXML.parseError.reason) & "</p>"
Else
    Set oRoot = oXML.selectSingleNode("//result/rowset")

    If oRoot Is Nothing Then
        response.write "Nothing!"
        response.end
    End If

    For Each oNode In oRoot.childNodes
        response.Write oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("characterID").Text
    Next
End If

Set oXML = Nothing
```

Edit: to get around the problem #3, and oddly also #4 (don't know why!), use this snippet to load the XML instead. For some reason, I think the code above isn't handling the gzip compressed stream correctly, but this code below does.

```
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set xh = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xh.open "GET", "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=BorisKarlov", False
xh.send
xml = xh.responseText
oXML.LoadXML xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @webaware, I have no way of altering the generated XML pages because they are generated by 3rd party, I just require the info generated, so if I understand you correctly (which I hope I do as I'm kinda noob at XML) I can go no further down this road.  Is there a different method to gather the required info from XML?

Comment: @BorisKarlov: if this answer fixes your problem, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/about) so that it won't keep showing up on lists of unanswered questions.